# #FIXED value VS (value) #IMPLIED in DTD

Tags: xml, dtd

How do these two statements differ in a DTD -

```
<!ATTLIST element-name attribute-name (value) #IMPLIED>
&
<!ATTLIST element-name attribute-name #FIXED value)
```

I tried the below two examples , both work the same way -

Example 1:

```
<?xml version ='1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>

<!DOCTYPE ContactBook[
<!ELEMENT ContactBook (Contact, Contact)>
<!ELEMENT Contact (Name, Phone)>
<!ELEMENT Name (#PCDATA|text)* >
<!ELEMENT text (#PCDATA) >
<!ELEMENT Phone (#PCDATA) >
<!ATTLIST Phone  type (Mobile) #IMPLIED>
]>


<ContactBook>
    <Contact>
        <Name><text>ABC</text></Name>
        <Phone>123</Phone>
    </Contact>
    <Contact>
        <Name>DEF<![CDATA[junk!]]></Name>
        <Phone type='Mobile'>456</Phone>
    </Contact>
</ContactBook>
```

Example 2:

```
<?xml version ='1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>

<!DOCTYPE ContactBook[
<!ELEMENT ContactBook (Contact, Contact)>
<!ELEMENT Contact (Name, Phone)>
<!ELEMENT Name (#PCDATA|text)* >
<!ELEMENT text (#PCDATA) >
<!ELEMENT Phone (#PCDATA) >
<!ATTLIST Phone  type CDATA #FIXED "Mobile">
]>


<ContactBook>
    <Contact>
        <Name><text>ABC</text></Name>
        <Phone>123</Phone>
    </Contact>
    <Contact>
        <Name>DEF<![CDATA[junk!]]></Name>
        <Phone type='Mobile'>456</Phone>
    </Contact>
</ContactBook>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand the difference is when you omit the attribute. In both cases you can do it but in `#IMPLIED` it won't get any, so the application that processes it could choose one, if any. While in `#FIXED` the attribute will get the value defined in the `DTD`, always.